# Reusing Admin forms for user views in django?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Django is making very nice forms after creating a models.py and an admin.py.

How can I reuse these forms (with the extra nice handling of foreign keys and many-to-many fields) in my own views?

ModelForm does only generate "simple" forms. Where do I get the extra batteries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually able to replicate those green buttons in my forms by following the instructions on this page: http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/

Answer (score 3):

A stock ModelForm will do almost all of what the admin does (ForeignKeys will turn into a dropdown select, ManyToManyFields will turn into a multiple-select).

The main exception would be the little green plus buttons for adding a new entry. It would be pretty hard to make those generic, as they depend on a number of admin-specific things: knowing where to find an add page for the linked model; JS to popup a window, close it on submit, and update the parent page; etc. You can dig into the admin and figure out how it implements those extra niceties, but there is not going to be a simple way to drop them into your code.

The other nicety you might be wanting is the filter_horizontal or filter_vertical alternative UIs for a ManyToManyField. Those are implemented as [ordinary form widgets](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L18), so the potential is there for reusing them in your own code, but I'm guessing it'll take some experimentation and customization to make it work properly.

Comment: The green plus buttons are the niceties I was looking for. So, this confirms that there is no simple way. Thanks!